# Printing the shortest path in a directed graph

Tags: prolog, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I have a directed, cyclic graph without weights. I want to find the shortest route between A and B (i.e. the one with the least hops).

This is the code i got so far:

```
path(A,B) :- walk(A,B,[]).

walk(A,B,V) :- edge(A,X), not(member(X,V)), (B=X); walk(X,B,[A|V]).

edge(a, b).
edge(b, c).
edge(a, d).
edge(c, a).
```

This code prints true, once for every route it finds. How can i print the path? And what would i have to do to find the path with the least hops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to unify an extra argument with what you have accumulated in `V` once you reach your termination condition:

```
path(A,B,P) :- walk(A,B,[],P).

walk(B,B,V,P) :- reverse(V,P).
walk(A,B,V,P) :- dif(A,B), edge(A,X), maplist(dif(X),V), walk(X,B,[A|V],P).
```

Once `A` and `B` are the same, it means that we don't have to walk the graph anymore. In that case we reverse the path that we accumulated in `V` as `P`, which gets "returned" from `path/3`.

Note: it is almost always clearer to put the code that checks the recursion termination as a separate rule, instead of using `;`.

To find the path with the least hops, you can find all paths from the two points you want, and then take the smallest one:

```
shortest_path(A,B,S) :-
    findall(P, path(A,B,P), Ps),
    maplist(prepend_length, Ps, Ls),
    sort(Ls, [[_,S]|_]).

prepend_length(P, [L,P]) :-
    length(P,L).
```

Comment: `s(X)` for `dif/2`! Using `maplist(dif(X), V)` instead of `\+ member...` makes this a lot more general! And: To find paths with the least hops *first*, I suggest: `?- length(Ps, _), path(A, B, Ps).`

Comment: @mat Your solution with `length/2` does not work if there is actually no path that exists. Though if there is one it is faster and less memory expensive; it would require a cut though.

Comment: Yes it's true, but it would not require a cut. In fact, adding a cut would incorrectly cut alternatives that may also be shortest. If you really only need one solution, use `once/1` when posting the query, but do not specialze the predicate unnecessarily.

Comment: @mat Not adding a cut would also permit alternatives that are not the shortest, and would eventually make the predicate go in an infinite loop because there is no boundary on the the second argument of  `length`. Finding that boundary requires to find all paths in the first place, unless I am mistaken.

Comment: You can use for example: `?- once((length(Ps0,L),path(_,_,Ps0)), length(Ps, L), path(A, B, Ps).` to get *all* shortest paths. You are right that this would loop infinitely if there is no shortest path.

Answer (score 1):

To yield the path, you'd need to add an argument to keep track of it; for example:

```
path(A,B,P) :- walk(A,B,[],P).
walk(A,B,V,[A,B]) :- edge(A,X), not(member(X,V)), (B=X).
```

(I'll leave the recursive case as an exercise.)

To find the shortest path, you could find them all (`findall`) & pick out the shortest.